# Surface Integral of Vector Field $\textbf{A}=(xz,0,yz)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, solution-verification, vector-fields, surface-integrals

I have to solve the following problem:

A cylinder of radius R in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with axis along the $z$-axis of a Cartesian coordinate system $(x,y,z)$ can be parametrised as $\textbf{x}(\theta,z) = (R\cos\theta, R\sin\theta, z)$. Evaluate the the surface integral of the vector field $\textbf{A} = (xz,0,yz)$ over the portion of the surface that lies between $z=0$ and $z=R$.

**My Approach**

1. I found the outward-pointing unit normal to the cylinder at the point $\textbf{x}(\theta,z)$.
   $$
   \frac{\partial \textbf{x}}{\partial \theta} \times \frac{\partial \textbf{x}}{\partial z} = \begin{vmatrix}
   \textbf{i} & \textbf{j} & \textbf{k}\;\\ 
   -R\sin\theta & R\cos\theta & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 1 
   \end{vmatrix} 
   = R\cos\theta\,\textbf{i} + R\sin\theta\,\textbf{j}
   $$
   so
   $$
   \biggl\lVert\frac{\partial \textbf{x}}{\partial \theta} \times \frac{\partial \textbf{x}}{\partial z} \biggr\rVert 
   = \sqrt{(R\cos\theta)^2 + (R\sin\theta)^2} = \sqrt{\!R^2} = R.
   $$

Thus our outward-pointing unit normal is
$$
\textbf{n} = \frac{\frac{\partial \textbf{x}}{\partial \theta} \times \frac{\partial \textbf{x}}{\partial z}}{\biggl\lVert \frac{\partial \textbf{x}}{\partial \theta} \times \frac{\partial \textbf{x}}{\partial z}\biggr\rVert} = \begin{bmatrix}
           \cos\theta \\
           \sin\theta\\
           0\\
         \end{bmatrix}.
$$

2. I rewrote $\textbf{A}$ as $\textbf{A} 
   = (Rz\cos\theta, 0, Rz\sin\theta)$.
3. I Rewrote and solved the integral:
   \begin{align}
   \iint_{S}^{} \textbf{A}\,d\textbf{S} 
   &= \int_{0}^{R} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \textbf{A} \cdot 
   \biggl( \frac{\partial \textbf{x}}{\partial \theta} \times \frac{\partial \textbf{x}}{\partial z} \biggr)\, d\theta\, dz \\ 
   &= \int_{0}^{R} \int_{0}^{2\pi} (Rz\cos\theta, 0, Rz\sin\theta) \cdot (R\cos\theta, R\sin\theta, 0)\, d\theta\, dz \\ 
   &= \int_{0}^{R} \int_{0}^{2\pi} R^2z\,(\cos\theta)^2\, d\theta\, dz \\ 
   &= \int_{0}^{R} R^2\pi z\, dz \\ 
   &= \frac{R^4\pi}{2}.
   \end{align}

Is anything wrong with my solution? Am I missing something? Any input would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: It looks fine ...